# ElasticSearch Logstash upload null value for date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to bulk upload documents into elasticsearch(6.3) using logstash (6.3.1). One of the fields in the document in date. 
Below is my mapping type 
`

```
{
  "mappings": {
      "users" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : { "type" : "text" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point"},
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }

   }
  }
}
```

If there is no date available then I set it as `null`.

Ex csv upload doc

`John, Seattle, null`

During the upload, logstash reads the value for date as `"null"` (`null with quotes`) and the upload to elasticsearch fails because its doesn't accept `"null"` as a valid input to date. 
My question is how to let elasticsearch accept `null` values (`null without quotes`) for date when uploading from logstash?

Comment: Downvoting because this question can be awnsered with a quick search in google. In the documentation , there is a full explanation about null handling  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html

Comment: This is not what I want. I clearly mentioned that when uploading from logstash, I want to replace null with quotes to without quotes

Comment: I don't think null is a supported value in logstash, you might to remove the date field. You can do it like this: `if [date] =~ /null/ {   mutate {    remove_field => [ "date" ]   }  }`

Comment: If you read the article you will see that null values are not supported and what are the ways to mediate in case of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set it to `null` (as a string in csv file data). Set it to nothing/no value as all (i.e. for any such field where the value is not present, your csv file can have `,,,`  blank values.

In your case, for ex: Set it like this:

```
John,Seattle,
Shenzi,Denver,2020-05-11
```

For the first row, when logstash will read csv file (ex: if you had `input { stdin{} }` in logstash's conf file then you'll `cat somefile.csv | logstash -f <logstash.conf>`) it'll treat the 3rd column value as '' (turning it into an ES index as a key=val pair like: `date: null` for free)